# Show that if $\langle f(x), x\rangle \leq 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb R^n$, then each solution of $x'(t)=f(x)$ is defined for all $t > t_0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n $ be a function of class $C^1$
>   and let $\left< \cdot \right>$ be an inner product in $\mathbb R^n$.
>   Show that if $\left<f(x), x\right> \leq 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb R^n$, then each solution of the initial value problem $x'(t)=f(x)$ is defined for all $t > t_0$.

For this ODE problem, my question is what this statement means and what we are supposed to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $V(x) = {1 \over 2} \|x\|^2$ (cf. Lyapunov function) and suppose $x$ is a solution of the system $\dot{x} = f(x)$. If we let $\phi(t) = V(x(t))$ then
$\phi'(t) = \langle \dot{x}(t), x(t) \rangle  = \langle f(x(t)), x(t) \rangle  \le 0$.

Hence any solution lies $\bar{B}(0,\|x(t_0)\|)$ for all $t \ge t_0$.

Since $f$ is $C^1$, it is Lipschitz on the closed ball and hence Picard's theorem shows that a solution exists for all $t \ge t_0$.