# Showing that an autonomous ODE has a solution defined for all time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the autonomous ODE $$x'(t)=f(x)$$ with initial condition $x(t_0)=x_0$. Assume that $(f(x),x) \leq 0$, where $(\cdot)$ is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$,

 I would like to show that this ODE has a solution defined for all $t > t_0$. I think I need to show that $|x(t)|^2$ is bounded, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: *Hint:* Compute the derivative of $|x(t)|^2 = \langle x(t), x(t) \rangle$.

Comment: Or look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3546129/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(f(x)%2Cx)%20%5Cleq%200%24%2C%20AND%20content%3AODE)